How to block access to "Settings" and adding extensions in Visual Studio Code?
How to block access to "Settings" and adding extensions in Visual Studio Code? The program is used by many users on one workstation.
I looked in the settings and didn't find it. There is no information on Google either.

Is this for a security reason or just because different users like different settings?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Users make a mess

I'm not aware of a way to do this. You can build with custom product.json to change marketplace URL, but that doesn't block users from installing from VSIX.
Aside: At this point, I wonder if building your own thing with monaco is more appropriate. Or you make a custom build of VS Code without these feature. Or maybe try to edit filesystem permissions to prevent adding files and directories under ~/.vscode and the default user-data directory's User/ subdirectory / remove write permissions on files under that directory (I haven't tried this and don't know if this works).
